# Django ChoiceField is automatically adding a text box..?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-haystack

My Django form is automatically adding a text input field as well as a drop down menu. I want a drop down menu to filter the results. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from django import forms

class FacetedProductSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

    desc = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('n', 'Ascending'), ('y', 'Descending')], label='', initial='y')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = dict(kwargs.get("data", []))

        self.retailer = data.get('retailer', [])
        self.location = data.get('location', [])
        super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).search()       

        if self.cleaned_data['desc'] == 'y':
            query = None

            sqs = sqs.order_by('-retailer')
        else:
            sqs = sqs.order_by('retailer')
        return sqs
```

results.html

```
<div class="tab-filter">
    <form id="searchformsort" action="" method="get" >
        <select id=sort class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-select"/>
            <option>Sort by</option>
            <option> {{ form }} </option>

        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ChoiceField:

```
widget=forms.Select,
```

from Documentation:

> A widget is Django’s representation of an HTML input element.

With the Widget your are telling to django to render the field with a  select

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, tried that and still seems to add a text search box to my form. Confusing...

Comment: uhm try to create a dummy form and pass it to the view by using the default django format like `class DummyForm(forms.Form):
    desc = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[('n', 'Ascending'), ('y', 'Descending')],
        label='',
        initial='y',
        widget=forms.Select
        )`